# Getting Spring property @Value without PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am not able to get property defined in spring application.properties with @Value annotation. Somehow I know that we have to register propertysourcesplaceholderconfigurer bean in rootConfig and this registering method is **static**.

```
 @Bean 
 public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {

     PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
     ClassPathResource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ] {
         new ClassPathResource("db.properties")
     };
     ppc.setLocations( resources );
     ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
     ppc.setSearchSystemEnvironment(true);
     return ppc;
}
```

The problem here is the **application.properties** from **cmis** and resource loader is initialized only the applicationContext is created. Once the applicationContext is done, inside rootConfig, through Environment.getProperty(XXX), can get the property value.

Is there anyother way?

### Edit

I wonder even I can access the property with @conditionOnProperty without using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Is there a way similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

**application.propertes**

```
application.angular.rooturl = http://localhost:8080/test
```

**Java Class where I use @value**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationPropertyConfig {

    public static String ROOTURL;

    @Value("${application.angular.rooturl}")
    public void setANGULAR_ROOTURL(String aNGULAR_ROOTURL) {
        ANGULAR_ROOTURL = aNGULAR_ROOTURL;
    }
}
```

Then I can get this value using , `ApplicationPropertyConfig.ROOTURL`